# Changing displacement over a sequence of frames

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, opticalflow

guys.

I've written a code to describe motion on interest points over a .avi video file. 
Here is the code:

```
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
VideoCapture capture("video.avi");


if (!capture.isOpened()) {
    cout << "ERROR OPENING VIDEO\n\n";
    return(0);
}

double rate = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); 
unsigned int numberFrames = (unsigned int) capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
int width = (unsigned int) capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
int height = (unsigned int) capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
unsigned int codec = (unsigned int) capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC);

Mat currentGray;
Mat previousGray;
vector< Point2f > points[2];
vector< Point2f > initial;
vector< Point2f > features;

vector< uchar > status;
vector< float > error;

int maxCorners = 500;  // maximum number of features to detect
double qualityLevel = 0.01;  // quality level for feature detection
double minDistance = 10; // min distance between two points

Mat frame, output;

VideoWriter createdVideo("output.avi", codec, rate, Size(width,height), 1);

for (unsigned frameCounter = 0; frameCounter < numberFrames; frameCounter++) {

    capture >> frame;

    if (frame.empty())
        break;

    imshow("Video", frame);
    cvtColor(frame, currentGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    frame.copyTo(output);


    if (points[0].size() <= 10){
        goodFeaturesToTrack(currentGray, // the image
            features, // the output detected features
            maxCorners, // the maximum number of features
            qualityLevel, // quality level
            minDistance); // min distance between two features

        // add the detected features to
        // the currently tracked features
        points[0].insert(points[0].end(),
            features.begin(), features.end());
        initial.insert(initial.end(),
            features.begin(), features.end());
    }

    if (previousGray.empty())
        currentGray.copyTo(previousGray);

    calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(previousGray, currentGray, // 2 consecutive images
        points[0], // input point positions in first image
        points[1], // output point positions in the 2nd image
        status, // tracking success
        error); // tracking error

    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < points[1].size(); i++) {
        // do we keep this point?

        if (status[i] && // if point has moved
            (abs(points[0][i].x - points[1][i].x) +
            (abs(points[0][i].y - points[1][i].y)) > 2))

            initial[k] = initial[i];
            points[1][k++] = points[1][i];
    }

    points[1].resize(k);
    initial.resize(k);


    for (int i = 0; i < points[1].size(); i++) {
        // draw line and circle
        line(output,
            initial[i], // initial position
            points[1][i],// new position
            Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
        circle(output,
            points[1][i],
            2,
            Scalar(0, 0, 255), -1);

    }

    std::swap(points[1], points[0]);
    cv::swap(previousGray, currentGray);

    createdVideo.write(output);

}

waitKey(0);
return(0);
}
```

My code tracks displacement of points frame by frame and keeps the **first** location of them until the end of video.
However, **I would like not the keep the location's points of the first frame**, but change them over time, i.e. changing the first point location with the second point location so on and then huge lines will not appear but only the displacement between two points in two frames.

Is there any possibility of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want the position of points in two frames, just use two vectors; one holding the keypoints from the last frame, and one holding keypoints from the previous frame. At the end of each iteration, just set the previous points to the current points. Something like this pseudocode:

```
// first frame
// detect keypoints
prev_frame_points = keypoints

// rest of the frames
for frame in frames: 
    // detect keypoints
    curr_frame_points = keypoints
    line(..., prev_frame_points, curr_frame_points, ...)
    prev_frame_points = curr_frame_points
```